# WooCommerce custom product order by ids specified

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to achieve WooCommerce Category product shown depend on product ids i have selected. For example In my `Shirt` category I have total 20 product and the ids are `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20` and I want to display them by my custom order what I choose.
not the default ordering like bellow images

[image]

I choose this 4 product and how other product will auto add in the query and I can

```
13,15,11,2
```

I made a custom query to override the original query like this

```
 add_filter('woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args', 'sswoocommerce_catalog_orderby');
    function sswoocommerce_catalog_orderby( $args ) {
        $args['post_type'] = 'product', 
        $args['post__in'] = [13,15,11,2],  // this are product id 
        $args['orderby'] = 'post__in'; 
        $args['order'] = 'ASC'; 
        return $args;
    }
```

Can anyone have better solution for this ? please help